# How to properly format boolean expressions in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I nearly have the code formatter in eclipse-cdt like I want it, but I have a problem with boolean expressions.

This is the output of the code formatter:

```
if (ACM_SlewRight)
    mStopWallSlewRight = (leftSide && absAngleCur > 900) || (rightSide && absAngleCur < 900);

}

return mStopWallSlewLeft||
mStopWallSlewRight ||
mStopWallBoom1_Up ||
mStopWallBoom1_Down ||
mStopWallBoom2_Up ||
mStopWallBoom2_Down ||
mStopWallTeleOut;
```

I would like to have it look like this:

```
if (ACM_SlewRight)
{
    mStopWallSlewRight = (leftSide && absAngleCur > 900) || 
                         (rightSide && absAngleCur < 900);

}

return mStopWallSlewLeft||
       mStopWallSlewRight ||
       mStopWallBoom1_Up ||
       mStopWallBoom1_Down ||
       mStopWallBoom2_Up ||
       mStopWallBoom2_Down ||
       mStopWallTeleOut;
```

I do not understand why the first part is not wrapped as I configured Max line width to 80 and this is 98. The return is wrapped by myself because the wrapper would also not do anything here.

I also tried all options I could find (especially in Line wrapping -> expressions). But I can not find a solution, are boolean expressions not supported?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate answer to your question is that you've likely found a bug in CDT's built-in formatter. You could [file it here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).

The more forward-looking answer is that CDT's built-in formatter has barely seen any maintenance in the last few years, and any such bug is therefore unlikely to be fixed (unless you contribute the fix yourself). On the other hand, there are much better-maintained C++ source formatters out there (like [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)) and plugins to integrate them into Eclipse (like [CppStyle](http://www.cppstyle.com/)) with which you are likely to have a much better experience.